# C# telerik winforms radDropDownList multiselect

Tags: c#, telerik, multi-select

I have enabled multiple selections in the radDropDownList with below code.

```
radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

This list has 10 options and each user can choose one to 10 of them
Now I want to retrieve the user selection that I saved in an array list
`ArrayList UserChoose = new ArrayList();`

```
UserChoose = getUserChoose("username");
```

How can I through the code,Return user selections to the radDropDownList?

```
radDropDownList.Select = UserChoose ?
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know does it worked for you or you still facing any problem. Best wishes :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways how you can achive that. It will be little complex but it will work for you I believe.
**Way 1:** 
As I think, you might not able to do that using only `radDropDownList`. If still you want to do that using `radDropDownList` then you have to customized `radDropDownList` like in the [telerik dicussion forum](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/dropdown-checkeddropdown-and-list/details/multi-select-drop-down-list). Source code link is [here](https://d585tldpucybw.cloudfront.net/docs/default-source/documents/ui-for-winforms/articles/multiselectdropdownlistcs.zip?sfvrsn=e4523e1c_0).

[image]

**Way 2:** 
You can use `RadMultiColumnComboBox`. It will be easy to implement. At the same time it has more features. Check link of telerik over here=>[RadMultiColumnComboBox Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/multicolumncombobox/how-to/multiple-selection).

[image: enter image de## Heading ##scription here]


 **Note:** Personally I support the latter one rather than the former one.So, way 2 is much more effective.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest replacement for a Windows Forms dropdown with multiple selection using Telerik is the [RadCheckedDropDownList](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/dropdown-listcontrol-and-checkeddropdownlist/checkeddropdownlist/checkeddropdownlist) control, that is intended to provide that particular functionality.

It is available since version 2018.1.116.